# Java nextInt() generates negative numbers

Tags: java, random

I am making a random line generator for fun. For some reason, the program does not make use of the maximum numbers I provided in the `nextInt().` Strangely, the only `nextInt()` that works properly is `space.`
Here is my code:

```
public class LineFractal extends Applet {
Random rnd = new Random();
int width = 640;
int height = 640;
int x = 1000;
int endy1 = rnd.nextInt(320);
int endx1 = rnd.nextInt(320);
int starty1 = rnd.nextInt(320);
int startx1 = rnd.nextInt(320);
int space = rnd.nextInt(25);
public void init() {
    setSize(width, height);
    Frame c = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    c.setTitle("Line Generator");
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    while (x > 0) {
        x -= 1;
        g.drawLine(startx1, starty1, endx1, endy1);
        endy1 += space;
        endx1 -= space;
    }
    g.drawString("Space: " + space, width-100, height-10);
    g.drawString("Y (End): " + endy1, width-100, height-20);
    g.drawString("Y (Start): " + starty1, width-100, height-30);
    g.drawString("X (End): " + endx1, width-100, height-40);
    g.drawString("X (Start): " + startx1, width-100, height-50);
}
}
```

Why is it doing this?

EDIT: Just ran it again, and the X (Start) and the Y (Start) do work, but the (End) integers do not. They will generate a completely random number, sometimes as low as -21842. But they are not always negative.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't overflow? Your while loop runs 1000 times and you're adding space to endy1 at each iteration.

Comment: Try printing out `endy1`, `endx1`, etc. _before_ your while-loop. It looks like you modify `endy1` and `endx1` within your while-loop (which runs 1000 times).

Comment: I don't think your description is accurate; you say that `nextInt()` is returning negative numbers, but you haven't explained where you're allegedly seeing them.

Comment: You should try to isolate your usage of the `Random` class into a smaller, contained example. Maybe a JUnit test or a Console app that does `println` calls. I doubt that [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) is doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @tasteslikejava assume `endy` is 0 and `space` is 21: 0 + 21 *1000 = 21000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Java `nextInt()` generates negative numbers

No, `nextInt()` -- the way you are calling it -- does not return negative numbers.

Your loop that repeatedly subtracts `space` from `endx1` is what's causing `endx1` to become negative.

Comment: I believe nextInt() does generates negative numbers nextInt(int) on the other hand....

Answer (score 6):

Facts:

- `endx1` can have an initial value between 0 and 319.
- `space` can have a value between 0 and 24.
- `x` starts at 1000

Once for each `x`, you decrease `endx1` by `space`, meaning that it can reach values as low as `0 - (1000 * 24) = -24000` or as high as `319 - (1000 * 0)`.

So, in essence, your code is an overly elaborate way to assign `endx1` a random value between -24000 and 319. Of course it's going to be negative most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int posRandomInt = rnd.nextInt( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
```

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a constant holding the maximum value an int can have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.